# Choice Mode does not effect on Custom Adapter with Layout

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, android-gridview

Previously i worked with GridView and set ChoiceMode to single and everything was OK.
Now i create my Custom Adapter with it's Layout.
And then added items to the GridView.
And set ChoiceMode to Single, As below you will see.
But Choice mode does not work in appearance and view.

Here is Custom Adapter :

```
  public class CarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Car>{

    public CarAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Car> carArrayList) {
        super(context, resource, carArrayList);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Car car = getItem(position);
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_car,parent, false);
        }

        TextView carName =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView carSIM = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        carName.setText(car.getName());
        carSIM.setText(car.getSIM());



        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And here is it's Layout XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_x="12dp"
        android:layout_y="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_x="157dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

And here is Main Activity :

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

    CarAdapter carAdapter;
    Car car;
    Car car2;
    Car car3;
    ArrayList<Car> carArrayList;
    GridView gridView;
    Button test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        carArrayList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        carAdapter = new CarAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, carArrayList);
        test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        car = new Car("Test", "aaa");
        car2 = new Car("Test2", "aaa");
        car3 = new Car("Test3", "aaa");
        Car car4 = new Car("Test4", "aaa");
        carArrayList.add(car);
        carArrayList.add(car2);
        carArrayList.add(car3);
        carArrayList.add(car4);
        gridView.setAdapter(carAdapter);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choice mode is : " + gridView.getChoiceMode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (gridView.isItemChecked(gridView.getCheckedItemPosition())) {
                String name = (carAdapter.getItem(gridView.getCheckedItemPosition())).getName();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here is " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is not true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

As you see i put a test Button and return the name of selected GridView Item.It returns the value,But with no checkable or selected View.

And Main Activity XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".DisplayActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="387dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:background="#abc"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Should i set it by myself?
If yes, where?

Any solution will appreciate.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

First create the array list. then create the adapter and then assign it as an adapter to grid view.

what you are doing is creating adapter first the  creating array-list and the setting it to grid view.

Comment: No chance,I did this
        carArrayList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        car = new Car("aa", "jj");
        car2 = new Car("aa", "aa");
        car3 = new Car("aa", "aa");
        carArrayList.add(car);
        carArrayList.add(car2);
        carArrayList.add(car3);
        carArrayList.add(car4);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        carAdapter = new CarAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, carArrayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(carAdapter);

Comment: When i select from GridView, it gets hilight for a sec.
 But with no tick or radio Button to select.